# When comparing two Series, how do I filter based on one Series?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Pandas Series. I have one list of numbers that I want to compare with another and I want to return True and False based on if one matches the other. Example:

```
phone_series = pd.Series(['5555555', '5542394', '3431111', '3432222'])
filter_list = pd.Series(['555', '222', '3431', '999'])
```

What I tried to use, was the `.isin` Pandas method, but it only matches exact patterns.

```
phone_series.str[:3].isin(filter_list)

0    True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

This is fine if the filter list was only 3 characters, then I could just use the first 3 characters in phone series and compare, but some of the characters in the list are 3, 4, or even 5. Here is what the output should be:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with tuple from `Series` called `filter_list` (same working if `list` instead `Series`):

```
print (phone_series.str.startswith(tuple(filter_list)))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```